# Base folder path via alternative to ExecutionContext.FunctionAppDirectory with Azure Function 2.x

Tags: azure, azure-functions

`ExecutionContext` is null via dependency injection via constructor, `ExecutionContext.FunctionAppDirectory` is required to get the base folder path.

Is there an alternative to `ExecutionContext.FunctionAppDirectory`?

When and where will ExecutionContext is available before function is invoked? So I can get the base path.

Answer (score 0):

The location of function app directory changes based on the environment in and the context in which the function app is running.

Here is a round about way of getting it. Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

```
// if running in azure  
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID")))
{
    string home = GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME");
    Path = System.IO.Path.Combine(home, "site", "wwwroot");
}
// running in non azure environments 
else
{
    Path = GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsScriptRoot");
}
```

Comment: I have the similar idea. One concern is the path on Azure, is it stable, or is it how Azure uses? Please provide info for the use of path on Azure, for example, offiical doc.

Comment: This is how Azure app service and Azure functions determines this path. It is stable and consistent across all the hosting environments. The wiki link on the Azure functions documents this partially here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Configuration-Settings

Comment: In the case of D:\home\site\wwwroot\foo. the solution above doesn't work. While ExecutionContext.FunctionAppDirectory might work.

Comment: Plus, please provide links that prove the solution is reliable.

Comment: You cannot change the base path of your function app. The base path is always wwwroot

Comment: please see this https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/26761#issuecomment-475908193